# How to convert guzzle psr7 response to an array

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I wish to retrieve contents of one `API` and use the contents in my blade.
If I return the response I'm able to see the contents as below

```
{"CUSTOMER_NO":"00001292","VAL_1":"51610"}
```

But I cannot able to retrieve the `CUSTOMER_NO` or `VAL_1` fields from the above output.
Conversion of `psr7` response to array or string also not allowed.
`json_decode((string)$response->getBody,True)` also doesnt return anything.
Im also not able to use the $response as array directly in my blade also.

My API code:

```
$sql="SELECT CUSTOMER_NO,VAL_1 from tablename where VAL_1=$test";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);     
oci_execute($stid);
$line = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($line);
```

My Controller Code:

```
$client=new Client();
        $url='http://test.com/test.php';
        $response=($client->request('POST',$url,[ 'form_params' => [
        'ac_no' => $ac_no,]],array()));
        return $response;
```

I want to take the values of `CUSTOMER_NO`,`VAL_1` separately / use the same in blade.
Kindly throw some light.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `->getBody()->getContents()` method to get json response.

```
   $response=($client->request('POST',$url,[ 'form_params' => ['ac_no' => $ac_no,]],array()));
   $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
   $res =json_decode($response,true);
```